# Are html get/post methods similar to http get/post verbs

Tags: html, post

Are 'GET' and 'POST' method definitions different for HTML and HTTP? This is what i could collect -

```
HTTP-GET - Requests data from a specified resource
HTTP-POST - Submits data to be processed to a specified resource
```

and

```
HTML-GET - form submit method, data appended to URL
HTML-POST - form submit method, data enclosed in HTTP request
```

Are the HTTP verbs related to HTML form-submit methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML, the attribute `method` in a `form` element specifies directly whether GET or POST is to be used in [form data submission](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.1). In addition, it specifies the way in which the form data set is transmitted in the request: in the URL or in the HTTP message body, encoded in one of a few alternative encodings (media types).

The [HTTP methods](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9) have been defined more abstractly: they do not specify the exact way in which the data is included in the request – this is left to be agreed at other protocol levels, such as HTML

Comment: thanks.
so it is safe to say that get and post may refer to either HTTP verbs or HTML form methods.